# VSTO 3 RibbonX getLabel Callback Failing

Tags: vsto

It seems I can not properly implement the callback for getLabel in VSTO 3 with XML defined RibbonX. What am I doing wrong here? Is there some holy grail of documentation that I am missing out on?

```
public string GetCustomLabel(IRibbonControl control) {

    return "Custom label";

    }
```

Comment: Here is where the callback is set:<button id="buttonRibbonOpenFromPCX" imageMso="FileOpenDatabase" onAction="RibbonOpenFromPCX_Click" label="Open from PCX" getLabel="GetCustomLabel" size="large" />

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out label can not be assigned before getLabel in the XML.